# Regarding norm-attaining functional

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $f\in X^*$, where $X$ is a complex normed linear space. I want to show that the real part of $f$ is norm attaining real linear functional iff $f$ is norm attaining complex linear.

Let $f$ be a norm attaining complex linear functional. Thus there exists $x_0\in B_X$ such that $\|f\|=|f(x_0)|$, where $B_X$ is the closed unit ball in $X$. I know that if $u$ is the real part of $f$, then $f(x)=u(x)-iu(ix)$ for all $x\in X$, $u$ is a bounded real linear functional and $\|f\|=\|u\|$.

Thus $\|u\|=|u(x_0)-iu(ix_0)|$. How to find $y_0\in B_X$ such that $|u(x_0)-iu(ix_0)|=|u(y_0)|$? I thought $\frac{x_0+ix_0}{\|x_0+ix_0\|}$ would work. But it didn't work. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|u\| = |f(x_0)| \neq 0$, then let
$$y_0 = \frac{u(x_0) + i u(ix_0)}{\|u\|}x_0.$$
Note that $\|y_0\| = \|x_0\| = \|u\|$. Further,
\begin{align*}
f(y_0) &= \frac{u(x_0) + i u(ix_0)}{\|u\|} f(x_0) \\ 
&= \frac{(u(x_0) + i u(ix_0))(u(x_0) - i u(ix_0))}{\|u\|} \\
&= \frac{|u(x_0) - i u(ix_0)|^2}{\|u\|} \\
&= \frac{\|u\|^2}{\|u\|} = \|u\| \in \Bbb{R}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $u(y_0) = \Re f(y_0) = \|u\|$, as required.

Comment: $y_0 = \frac{u(x_0) - i u(ix_0)}{\|u\|}x_0$?

Comment: No, as I wrote. The idea is to "rotate" the vector back to being a "real" vector (with respect to $f$, anyway) by scalar multiplying it by a constant of modulus $1$.

Comment: But how $(u(x_0) + i u(ix_0))(u(x_0) - i u(ix_0))=|u(x_0) - i u(ix_0)|^2$?

Comment: They are conjugates of each other, right? We have $z \overline{z} = |z|^2$.

Comment: Ohh yes. Got it.Thanks!